# Accordion Problems

Tags: jquery, html, slidedown

Lets get straight to it: the theory is an accordion which is one way - clicking on a header in the accordion will slide down content and clicking on a separate div inside will slide its parent (the header) back up. I want to use this as I would prefer an accordion which doesn't just slide back up whenever another header is clicked. Actually, as I don't know too much jquery, my theory probably won't work, so if there're any easier alternatives out there I'll use them! This is what I've got so far, but it's definitely not working. I hope this isn't too vague:

```
$('#nav > li > a').click(function() {
    $(this).find(:first-child).slideDown(200); });
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's a little vague at present, can you please put your example up on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Post your html/css/javascript in here and on jsfiddle

Comment: Are you saying that you have more number of active tabs in a accordion

Comment: The problem is that the tabs aren't opening. I have a few tabs, and I want it to be easily adjustable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3XUJV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

There is a [plugin](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FlexibleSlideToTopAccordion/index.html)

In this the accordion tab will not closed even when you opened the next tab.

If you want to close it try [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FlexibleSlideToTopAccordion/index2.html)

Also check some in useful plugins in this [Site](http://vivekdragon.wordpress.com/)

If you need the code Then this is what we do in it

```
 function() {

 var instance   = this;

 // open / close item
        this.$items.find('a:first').bind('click.accordion', function( event ) {

            var $item           = $(this).parent();

            // close any opened item if oneOpenedItem is true
            if( instance.options.oneOpenedItem && instance._isOpened() && instance.current!== $item.index() ) {

                instance._toggleItem( instance.$items.eq( instance.current ) );

            }

            // open / close item
            instance._toggleItem( $item );

            return false;

        });
```

Comment: Well, I want to be able to understand it a bit, unless it really is that hard.